# Can you manually call an sfDoctrineRoute from within an action in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony1, routes, doctrine

As the question says.  I'd like to dispatch to an sfDoctrineRoute from within another action, but I'd like to preserve the current request.  That way I'm not redirecting and losing the current request info....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the forward() method in case it's what you're looking for:

http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfAction

As a side note, I'm sure you have your reasons for wanting this but I'd probably approach so that whatever you need from that other action is contained in the models. This way when you call it, you can pass the request parameters to it and "preserve" the current request - wherever in your application you're calling it from. If you really need to call another action, then I'd go ahead push the request to it fully. You can always redirect/forward and pass the request parameters with it.